# Monitor goes black after a few seconds

Tags: display, lcd

I have a widescrceen Samsung LCD that goes black after it's been on for 5-10 seconds.  Once the screen goes black, turning the monitor off then on again brings the image back for a few seconds.  I've turned the brightness down quite a bit and it's staying on now, but this doesn't seem like a desirable permanent solution.  It's worked fine for about a year until now.  Any ideas?

Comment: I assume you've checked the cables and that the connectors are seated properly.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like your backlight inverter may be going.

When it goes black, can you see a ghost-like image of the graphics you expect on the screen (try looking at it from an angle)?

If you can, then that's definitely the backlight system failing.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem for all LCD screen TV. LCD screen goes black after a few seconds of turning on. When you repeat it's still the same.

You have a faulty inverter causing the back light of the LCD not functioning. Check for a bloated capacitor on the power supply and inverter circuit board. This capacitors can be seen visually by looking the top of the capacitors. If it is not flat these capacitors might be the problem.

If you tested it with a multi tester it is OK, but if the TV is power on, capacitors is no longer working as normal. Try replacing the bloated capacitors. Also, there are some capacitors that may have causing the problem. Try to replace the high voltage capacitors (light blue in color) located in the inverter circuit board. Replace all $ or 5 pcs capacitor. Usually the value are 12pf by 3KV and 4.7KV by 3KV.

Goodluck.

Benjie Ramos (Philippines)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
I went to my local Comp shop and had the inverter replaced for $20 plus 15 minutes. No problems with it since.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same thing happen with my Samsung 55" LED TV- the screen goes black with no sound 10 seconds after starting,  but pressing the channel button shows good signal and he channel still selected. You can change channel but screen stays blank and silent. Turn on/off and it does it again.

After messing about a bit I found that simply pressing 'source' and pressing the centre button to (re)select the TV tuner fixed the problem. (you can see the little window top right showing the tv tuner screen next to 'screen mirroring', HDMI1 et al)

This has happened 3 times in 6 months, prob a software issue. Hope this helps.