# Monitor blacks out when switched on but works fine when switched off and on several times

Tags: display

When I turn my LCD monitor on there is a brief but dim image on the screen for about a second and then it disappears. If I turn the monitor off and on again the same happens again but each time the image is a little brighter. After about 6 times of doing this the monitor will come on fully and stay on until at some point I turn it off and I must go through the above again to turn it on.

I note a couple of questions already on Superuser that point to the inverter as being the problem (e.g. [this](https://superuser.com/questions/100492/monitor-goes-black-after-a-few-seconds)) but I was wondering, as my monitor works continually once it does come on after five or six times turning it on and off again, could there be another cause or something I can do to get it to work without replacing components (i.e. something is just loose and can be tightened)?

Thanks

Comment: my guess is the florescent bulb in the back of the monitor is starting to go. I've not heard of folks trying to service that part, but I'm sure they are out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got what sounds like 2 seconds to black. Effectively it's a component failure inside the monitor, usually a capacitor or several capacitors are failing.

http://www.badcaps.net - Probably one of the best resources for troubleshooting your particular problem.

Comment: Thanks for that phrase "2 seconds to black" (although it's more like 0.5 seconds in my case) - I had not heard that before. A search on that phrase has brought up a lot of useful results including videos. I have not noticed any examples of working when turning it on and off several times but no doubt it's a component failure that will require repair or replacement. Thanks.

Comment: For anyone's future reference, this topic is good: http://www.badcaps.net/forum/showthread.php?t=10419.

Convinced me not to bother trying to repair myself :)